# jQuery change function one works the first time

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

We are altering text in a text area when a select field changes in a modal. It works the first time the page loads, but when the modal is closed and reloaded the updating does not work anymore:

```
   <script>
    $('#suspension_type').change(function(event){
        var template = $("textarea#message").val(),
                value = $(this).val(),
                content = "";

        if(value == "--Choose--"){
            content = template.replace('Full', "[[SUSPENSION_TYPE]]")
                    .replace('Reduced', "[[SUSPENSION_TYPE]]")
                    .replace('Vacation', "[[SUSPENSION_TYPE]]");
        } else {
            content = template.replace("[[SUSPENSION_TYPE]]", value)
                    .replace('Full', value)
                    .replace('Reduced', value)
                    .replace('Vacation', value);
        }
        $("textarea#message").val(content);
    });
</script>
```

How would you force the textarea content to be updated on the change event?

EDIT: Updated function. Still not working, How does delegation work?

Comment: Any reason `content` is global?

Comment: might be because the element `#suspension_type` is recreated(dynamically)... try event delegation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @Arun.  Delegation worked:

```
$('#suspendModal').delegate('select.suspension_type', 'change', function(){
  // Code
});
```